# The place of buttons, label and widgets (python)

Tags: python, canvas, widget

In the windows, there are two widgets including Canvas and Listbox, two buttons, and a label. Based on the code that I have written, now is look like this:

[image]

But what I want is slightly different, mainly the place is different:

[image: suppose to like this]

And here is my code:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    master.title("testing")
    self._master = master

    self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
    self.frame.pack()

    menubar=tk.Menu(master)
    master.config(menu=menubar)
    filemenu=tk.Menu(menubar)
    menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)
    filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command=self.open_file)

    self._label=tk.Label(master,text='testing').pack()

    self._button=tk.Button(master,text='testing',command=self.testing).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    self._button=tk.Button(master,text='testing',command=self.testing).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    self.list = tk.Listbox(master, bg='white')
    self.list.insert(1, "testing")
    self.list.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill = tk.BOTH)

    self._canvas = tk.Canvas(master, bg='white')
    self._canvas.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: I recommend abandoning `pack()` and using `grid()`. Also, don't chain your geometry management methods like that - in your current code, `self._button` is a reference to `None`, the value returned by `pack()`.

Comment: If I can only use `pack()` instead of `grid()`? I haven't learn it yet. But what does it mean by a reference to `None`?

Comment: If you were to `print(self._button)`, it would print `None`.

Comment: If I only use `pack()`, should I create a new area(just for saving the buttons and label) and this area on the top left?